# Should Node.js module developers use Underscore.js?

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I'm working on my 1st Node.js module, and having to do common utility stuff like check types, looping etc.

The native JS for some of this stuff is pretty ugly. Underscore.js makes it more readable and adds a lot of new features too. But if I don't need the new stuff, should I use Underscore or just do it the hard way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In node.is you can rely on having some ES5 stuff, array iteration functions and utility functions like isArray. In my node modules I never used underscore and had, due to array iteration functions like map, forEach never the need to use underscore or lodash.

I would not avoid a underscore dependency in case I'd really need it. The node.js platform relies on small modules depending on a couple of small modules itself. So why not depend on underscore.

Comment: `_.isEmpty` function?

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason to avoid using a module that makes your life easier. And, it just so happens, that underscore.js is the most depended upon package in the npm registry (as of the time of this answer, according to https://npmjs.org/). So yea, no reason to avoid it.

Comment: -1: Don't look at the github starts or npm installations to decide which module to use.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas: Care to explain?

Comment: Because being popular doesn't mean being good. I've tried a lot of popular modules and about a 40% of them are just bad/bugged/not really useful. There are a lot of modules that are not popular that are really good. Being popular helps to take a decision but you should not install and use a module just because it's popular.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas: OP came asking the community if Underscore.js is something that should be used. I think by being the number one most dependent package, the community has kind of spoken. Furthermore, not using popularity as a measure for anything is your personal preference. Don't present it as fact and down vote because of it.

Comment: @BFree I would agree with Gabriel that relying on popularity alone is a mistake. Programmers can be surprisingly sheep-like. Be skeptical. Hell, be a little arrogant and curmudgeonly. You'll thank you when you start writing mobile apps in webviews and you don't have to figure which of 38 overlapping dependencies are causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used underscore nor async on real projects. Once you know how to code good javascript it's not necessary to use any helper library. For example, functions that should execute in serie and are asynchronous it's pretty easy to do with a simple "recursive while loop", you don't need to load any library.

But at the end this is a personal preference. Use external libraries if you feel comfortable with them.

Advice: Don't look at the github starts or npm installations to decide which module to use. Being popular doesn't mean being good. I've tried a lot of popular modules and about a 40% of them are just bad/bugged/not really useful. There are a lot of modules that are not popular that are really good. Being popular helps to take a decision but you should not install and use a module just because it's popular.

Answer (score 2):

Underscore does the right thing, which is check for all the native es5 methods first, meaning you won't have much in the way of performance loss on native methods getting replaced with slower non-native versions that basically do the same thing ([code here](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html)):

```
var
    nativeForEach      = ArrayProto.forEach,
    nativeMap          = ArrayProto.map,
    nativeReduce       = ArrayProto.reduce,
    nativeReduceRight  = ArrayProto.reduceRight,
    nativeFilter       = ArrayProto.filter,
    nativeEvery        = ArrayProto.every,
    nativeSome         = ArrayProto.some,
    nativeIndexOf      = ArrayProto.indexOf,
    nativeLastIndexOf  = ArrayProto.lastIndexOf,
    nativeIsArray      = Array.isArray,
    nativeKeys         = Object.keys,
    nativeBind         = FuncProto.bind;
```

Note: prototypes assigned to "Proto" vars earlier.

That said, I'm pretty sure V8 has most if not all of these. Being of client-side dev origins I'd be delighted simply to use the raw naked thing without having to think about how or what library is best for dragging IE kicking and screaming out of the stone age this time, providing the built-in methods aren't as ugly as the DOM API and I would say these aren't.

If underscore does more for you than the above then by all means use it. If it doesn't, I'd consider it a waste of space. All it really does on the browser is give you fallback methods for the older browsers which aren't a going concern in Node. It's light though. I wouldn't object either way if you were on my team and didn't want to write your own versions of something uniquely handled by underscore but would prefer the direct native method names/args, etc. in my own code on the principle of disliking dependencies anywhere I don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

I use underscore in modules that are shared with the browser, not to depend on ES5. Also  Underscore has quite a few very useful methods that are not available in ES5, so it would make sense to read their manual page.